# How to identify malloc calls from main executable

Tags: intel-pin

I have a simple program that calls malloc, and I'm trying to develop a pintool to catch this direct call to malloc from the main executable.

Using malloctrace.cpp from SimpleExamples (comes with the SDK):

```
VOID Image(IMG img, VOID *v)
{
    RTN mallocRtn = RTN_FindByName(img, MALLOC);
    if (RTN_Valid(mallocRtn))
    {
        RTN_Open(mallocRtn);
        RTN_InsertCall(mallocRtn, IPOINT_BEFORE,(AFUNPTR)Arg1Before, IARG_ADDRINT, MALLOC, IARG_G_ARG0_CALLEE, IARG_END);
        RTN_Close(mallocRtn);
    }
}
```

I'm catching many malloc calls, both oriented by my own code or by libraries used by it.

Using objdump, I see the call to malloc:

```
callq  4003b8 <malloc@plt>
```

which starts with a malloc@plt. 
Browsing the routines in my main executable I do see a .plt routine, but I cannot tell if it belongs to malloc or any other external function.

I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: What is exactly your question? If it's `Does malloc@plt belongs to malloc implementation?`, the answer is no. `malloc@plt` belongs to the binary making the call. It **does** call the malloc implementation from the libc once the target is resolved by the runtime linker.

Comment: My question is: how can I catch the malloc calls directly originated by my code? (as opposed to all malloc calls, where many of them came from assisting code such as libc and etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add information to your analysis callback about the who called  the malloc() function. The easiest way to do this is to add `IARG_RETURN_IP` to your `RTN_InsertCall()` call and change Arg1Before accordingly.

Then, you can use `IMG_IsMainExecutable(IMG_FindByAddress(...))` on the return IP in Arg1Before to see if this call came from the main executable.

Comment: Thank you for this helpful comment!